# decide if a number is real or integer, based on queues contents (if statements)

Tags: c++, queue

I'm reading in data from a file, character by character,at the end of reading, i need to be able to print out if the value was a real or an integer.

I've read in the data with get(), and stored them into  2 different queues, if first part will be integerQueue, if a '.' is read in, then switch the rest of the data into realQueue. Then print out accordingly.

Having problems in the printing. Just keeps labeling everything into Integer: then the correct value.

```
else if(isdigit(temp) || temp == '.')
    {
            integerQueue.push(temp);
            char temp2 = readFile.get();
            while(isdigit(temp2))
            {
                integerQueue.push(temp2);
                temp2 = readFile.get();
            }
            if( temp == '.')
            {
                realQueue.push(temp);
                temp2 = readFile.get();
                while(isdigit(temp2))
                    {
                        realQueue.push(temp2);
                        temp2 = readFile.get();
                    }
            }
            if(realQueue.empty())
            {
            writeFile <<"Integer:       ";
                while(!integerQueue.empty())
                {
                writeFile <<integerQueue.front();
                integerQueue.pop();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                writeFile<<"Real:       ";
                while(!integerQueue.empty())
                {
                writeFile <<integerQueue.front();
                integerQueue.pop();
                }
                while(!realQueue.empty())
                {
                writeFile <<realQueue.front();
                realQueue.pop();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Reduce the code to the smallest you can that still compiles, runs, and shows the problem.

Comment: input is from a file, using readFile.get()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10th line: `if( temp == '.')` - you are reading the first char that enters this part of code instead of the last one that was read (and one which eventually would make the while loop break).
You should check if temp2 equals '.', instead of temp.

Comment: thanks a alot, hours of coding makes me miss small things, thanks again

Comment: You could prevent these sort of mistakes by giving your variables good names and tidy up the code a little., there is no reason for these much of duplicated code.

Comment: ...or using different approach: read a line or chunk of data without whitespaces and then check if those are only digits & if there is dot. Using queues when you can easily use for-loop with linear data is a bit of an overkill.